# Ionic document scanner application

Tags: ionic2, cordova-plugins, ionic3, ionic-native, ionic-cloud

I am looking for a plugin or a way where I can implement the same idea as "document scanner" into an Ionic application in which when you open the camera it detects the document borders and clarifies the photo after capturing it.

Is there is any tutorial or any one can record to me a video where I can benefit from it to implement this feature, since I need it for my application that I build for my university senior project.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: https://github.com/doo/scanbot-sdk-example-ionic2 check this link

Comment: @kishore.k.vaishnav Thank u for your comment, it’s worked for me 

Comment: @kishore.k.vaishnav You can put that as an answer. Please do that.